# Расположение блоков в Grid CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, css-grid

Ребят, помогите с помощью Grid CSS сделать структуру, как на картинке. Родитель должен занимать все пространство экрана. Только познакомился с этим стилем и не могу найти решение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Где ваш код? Что именно не получается? Здесь кода на 10 строк не больше

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Не знаю что тут сложного, но добавлю формальный ответ:

```css
.item1 { grid-area: header; }
.item2 { grid-area: menu; }
.item3 { grid-area: content; }

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'menu header header header header header'
    'menu content content content content content'
    'menu content content content content content';
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">Header</div>
  <div class="item2">Menu</div>
  <div class="item3">Content</div>
</div>
```

[Источник](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)

*Update:*

Есть хороший ресурс, помимо вышеуказанного, где вы можете в игровой форме разобраться с сеткой, называется: [Grid Garden](http://cssgridgarden.com/)

Comment: благодарю за ответ и за полезную ссылку. Не хватает времени до конца разобраться с гридами. А теперь надеюсь меньше времени понадобится

Comment: @Alexandr_TT а я благодарен тебе, за подробные посты по SVG, читаю их с удовольствием и некоторые даже уже применял. Кстати, с svg-art тоже много чего для себя нового открыл.

Comment: благодарю за отзыв. Может быть подвигнет меня наконец заняться сайтом. А то сюда всё, а на сайт почти ничего уже почти 2 года.:)

Answer (score 5):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
}
.wrapper div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#sidebar {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  
  <div id='sidebar'>sidebar</div>
  <div id='header'>header</div>
  <div id='content'>content</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px 400px;;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 400px;
}

.container1 {
    border: 3px solid brown;
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 2;
}

.container2 {
    border: 3px solid green;
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
}

.container3 {
    border: 3px solid blue;
    grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="container1"></div>
 <div class="container2"></div>
 <div class="container3"></div>
</div>
```

Вот мое решение