# Неправильно ведут себя пустые ячейки в CSS grid, заданные свойством grid-template-areas

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, css-grid

Делаю грид на CSS, ориентируясь на шпаргалку: https://tuhub.ru/posts/css-grid-complete-guide#prop-grid-template-areas

Там написано:

> grid-template-areas
>
> ...
>
> Точка означает пустую ячейку.

и приведен пример:

```
grid-template-areas: 
"header header header header"
"main main . sidebar"
"footer footer footer footer";
```

который выдает нормальный результат (пустая ячейка находится где-то посередине).

Пытаюсь сделать похожую конструкцию, но с двумя пустыми ячейками, которые находятся по краям сетки:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zyLOqz

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 5px;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-areas: "headerBg1 header headerBg2"
                       ". mainContent ."
                       "footerBg1 footer footerBg2";
  grid-gap: 2px;
}

.header { grid-area: header; }
.headerBg.1 { grid-area: headerBg1; }
.headerBg.2 { grid-area: headerBg2; }
.mainContent { grid-area: mainContent; }
.footer { grid-area: footer; }
.footerBg.1 { grid-area: footerBg1; }
.footerBg.2 { grid-area: footerBg2; }
```

```html
<div class="headerBg 1">Left header</div>
<div class="headerBg 2">Right header</div>
<div class="header">
  Header
</div>
<div class="mainContent">

  Main content<br/> Main content<br/> Main content
</div>
<div class="footerBg 1">Left footer</div>
<div class="footerBg 2">Right footer</div>
<div class="footer">
  Footer
</div>
```

ключевое тут это:

```
grid-template-areas: 
    "headerBg1 header headerBg2"
    ". mainContent ."
    "footerBg1 footer footerBg2";
```

ВОПРОС: почему блоки Left footer (`footerBg1`) и Right footer (`footerBg2`) находятся там, где должны быть пустые ячейки? Ожидается, что они будут в одной строке с блоком `footer`.

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/926311/262779

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так должно работать:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 5px;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1024px auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "headerBg1 header headerBg2"
    ". mainContent ."
    "footerBg1 footer footerBg2";
  grid-gap: 2px;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
}

.headerBg1 {
  grid-area: headerBg1;
}

.headerBg2 {
  grid-area: headerBg2;
}

.mainContent {
  grid-area: mainContent;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}

.footerBg1 {
  grid-area: footerBg1;
}

.footerBg2 {
  grid-area: footerBg2;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerBg1">Left header</div>
<div class="headerBg2">Right header</div>
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="mainContent">
  Main content<br> Main content<br> Main content
</div>
<div class="footerBg1">Left footer</div>
<div class="footerBg2">Right footer</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

Comment: Точки как работали так и работают,  там просто ошибки были. Надеюсь я вам помог.

Comment: А... понял. названия классов, начинающиеся с цифры, неправильные.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, проблема в совершенно другом:

> ```
> <div class="footerBg 1">Left footer</div>
> ```
>
> ```
> .footerBg.1 {grid-area: footerBg1;}
> ```

Css не позволяет называть классы начиная с цифры.

Рекомендую просто взять и переименовать.

---

В принципе это можно обойти через селектор атрибута:

```
.footerBg[class~="1"] {grid-area: footerBg1;}
```

или при помощи [хака с экранированием](https://benfrain.com/when-and-where-you-can-use-numbers-in-id-and-class-names/) (у меня в хроме работает):

```
.footerBg.\31 {grid-area: footerBg1;}
```

---

Кстати, с частями хэдера тот же косяк, но они чисто случайно встали на свои места.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 5px;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-areas: "headerBg1 header headerBg2"
                       ". mainContent ."
                       "footerBg1 footer footerBg2";
  grid-gap: 2px;
}

.header { grid-area: header; }
.headerBg.h1 { grid-area: headerBg1; }
.headerBg.h2 { grid-area: headerBg2; }
.mainContent { grid-area: mainContent; }
.footer { grid-area: footer; }
.footerBg.\31 { grid-area: footerBg1; }
.footerBg[class~="2"] { grid-area: footerBg2; }
```

```html
<div class="headerBg h1">Left header</div>
<div class="headerBg h2">Right header</div>
<div class="header">
  Header
</div>
<div class="mainContent">

  Main content<br/> Main content<br/> Main content
</div>
<div class="footerBg 1">Left footer</div>
<div class="footerBg 2">Right footer</div>
<div class="footer">
  Footer
</div>
```